# Should I ask my doubt and later answer it on my own?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, self-answer

So I was studying numerical methods from my class notes and got this doubt which I had asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4813222/955582).

My notes are short and quick so they skip over a lot of detail. Later, I followed a textbook and my doubts got cleared. I decided to answer my own question and accept it.

Is this behaviour desirable for this site?

I personally feel a bit awkward to accept my own answer.

Suppose, if I come across some doubt while trying to understand something and later somehow my doubt gets cleared, either by following a video tutorial or a textbook, 
Can I ask and answer my doubt if I feel it's worth having a record of it here? (Of course, I will avoid posting duplicates by making use of Approach$0$.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with writing--and accepting--your answer. Accepting an answer expresses what the OP prefers. That's the point of the checkmark. If the OP happens to prefer their answer, then that's their business. Everyone considers their answers useful even in their post. Otherwise, why write them?

Comment: Yes, and please do this! There are too many unanswered questions on the site. I have asked and later answered my own questions many times on this site

Answer (score 21):

The short answer to this question is yes. And the long answer is included in the list of questions in the site's help center. You can check [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and read the details.

Answer (score 6):

Self-answered content is very welcomed. Additional feature of the math SE, if you can answer your own question better as the >=MSc guys here, then you are likely one of them, making you an irreplaceable member of the site.

You do not get the +2 for accepting your own answer.